# Sum and integral and limit

Tags: real-analysis

Good morning. I want prove that:

$\displaystyle\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{s = 0}^n {\frac{{n^2 }}{{\left( {n + s} \right)\left( {n^2  + s^2 } \right)}}}  = \frac{{\pi  + \ln \left( 4 \right)}}{8}
$

I do

$\displaystyle\begin{array}{l}
 \frac{1}{{1 + x + x^2  + x^3 }} = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{{1 + x}} - \frac{{x - 1}}{{1 + x^2 }}} \right) \\ 
  \Rightarrow \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{1 + x + x^2  + x^3 }}}  = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{1 + x}}}  - \int\limits_0^1 {\left( {\frac{{x - 1}}{{1 + x^2 }}} \right)dx} } \right) \\ 
 \left[ {\frac{1}{2}\ln \left( {x + 1} \right) - \frac{1}{4}\ln \left( {x^2  + 1} \right) + \frac{1}{2}\tan ^{ - 1} \left( x \right)} \right]_0^1  = \frac{{\pi  + \ln \left( 4 \right)}}{8} \\ 
 \end{array}$

Thank you advance.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you've already answered your question.

Basically, divide the numerator and denominator of the summand by $n^3$ to get:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{s = 0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{s}{n}\right)\left(1+\left(\dfrac{s}{n}\right)^2\right)}$

This is a Riemann sum for $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\,dx}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}$, which you have evaluated to be $\dfrac{\pi+\ln 4}{8}$.